# PowerBI-JavaScript: Failed to switch from desktop view to mobile view

Tags: powerbi-embedded

To workaround the issue I submitted in separate thread
[PowerBI-JavaScript: MobileLandscape layout isn't included in the reports connected from the official samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363842/powerbi-javascript-mobilelandscape-layout-isnt-included-in-the-reports-connect)

I meant to initialize the PowerBI embed with the desktop settings like below.

```
settings: {
    filterPaneEnabled: true,
    navContentPaneEnabled: false
}
```

Then check if **MobilePortrait** and **MobileLandscape** layouts are included using the function **hasLayout**:

- If either of them is included, call **updateSettings** to change the layout from desktop to proper mobile layout
- If none are of them is included, keep the desktop layout

However, that appears switch from desktop to mobile layouts isn't supported, the report insist in desktop layout and no error throw, did I miss anything or is this a bug of the PowerBI JS library?

P.S. We're using powerbi-client v2.5.1

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd take a look at (https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/blob/master/src/report.ts#L315), you'd see that there is the URL parameter of `isMobile=true` added to the `embedUrl` in the case of mobile layout in the config.

try adding this explicitly in your `embedUrl` since you're loading the report in desktop and only after that changing to mobile.